# TypeError: products.map is not a function. how do I fix this

Tags: reactjs

I've looked at similar questions, but haven't found an answer that actually works.  Here is my code for GridView:

```
const GridView = ({ products }) => {
         return (
         <Wrapper>
            <div className="products-container">
               {products.map((product) => {
                return <Product key={product.id} {...product} />
              })}
             </div>
          </Wrapper>
       )
      }
```

here is my code for ProductList:

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const {filtered_products:products} = useFilterContext();

  return <GridView products={products}>games list</GridView>
}
```

here is my code for FilteredContext:

```
const initialState = {
  filtered_products:[],
  all_products:[]
}
  
const FilterContext = React.createContext()

export const FilterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const {products} = useProductsContext();
  const[state,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type:LOAD_PRODUCTS, payload:products})
  },[products])
  
  return (
      <FilterContext.Provider value={{...state}}>
      {children}
    </FilterContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is in FilterContext?

Comment: `products` is not an array, you should check what is `filtered_products` from `useFilterContext()`

Comment: FilterContext has been added

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional rendering, in case of `products` is `null` or `undefined` then you might get this error.

```
const GridView = ({ products }) => {
         return (
         <Wrapper>
            <div className="products-container">
               {products && products.map((product) => {
                return <Product key={product.id} {...product} />
              })}
             </div>
          </Wrapper>
       )
      }
```

also, make sure that products is an array.

Comment: products is an array

Answer (score 1):

add **Elvis operator** (? question mark is Elvis operator) after the `products` for map, this operator check if `products`  isn't null, run the map code and if it is null won't run the map

```
const GridView = ({ products }) => {
   return (
       <Wrapper>
            <div className="products-container">
               {products?.map((product) => {
                return <Product key={product.id} {...product} />
              })}
             </div>
       </Wrapper>
   )
}
```

refer to this link [for more info about what is Elvis operator?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: products isn't null

Answer (score -1):

In the ProductList you should be passing `filtered_products` instead of products to the GridView

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const {filtered_products} = useFilterContext();

  return <GridView products={filtered_products}>games list</GridView>
}
```

Additionally make sure the product variable is defined before using map on it. You can do that using conditional rendering https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

```
const GridView = ({ products }) => {
         return (
         products && <Wrapper>
            <div className="products-container">
               {products.map((product) => {
                return <Product key={product.id} {...product} />
              })}
             </div>
          </Wrapper>
       )
      }
```

Comment: your response is quite wrong, he renamed `filtered_products` to `products`, there is no issue in this. and the solution you present would work if products is undefined or null, but that's not the case that causes the specific error.